# Angular 2- Is someone familiar with the use of bootstrap-multiselect?

Tags: typescript, angular, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to use this plugin: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Studio.Html5/Scripts/typings/bootstrap.multiselect/bootstrap.multiselect.d.ts

it is working with static values but suddenly when i want to use a loop trough an array it does not showing any results.. Maybe some of you guys had this issue before.

Here is the template code:

```
 <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option *ngFor="#list of checks">{{list}}</option>
</select>
```

and here the class code:

```
    ngOnInit() {
    $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
}
```

Nothing is wrong with the code but maybe someone did had the same issue..

Comment: I know how to do it with normal javascript but i want to use angular syntax

Comment: I'm also looking for some help here. I'm trying to use this one : http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect but i can not manage to get it right...

Comment: @frénésie all ready found an solution?

Comment: I did a home made implementation, i was faster than struggling with an old JQuery plug-in.

Comment: @frénésie can you show me?

Comment: My home made multiselect is super specific show showing you the code is pointless. Nevertheless, i can explain to you how i did it. Basically I have a component for the multiselect that will get the values to display from a service, on ngInit() (or it could be from a @Input decorator on a component's proprety). Then in the view i  have a <div> that looks like a select (with CSS) and this <div> has a binding on a [ngClass] that will display an absolute positionned <div> underneath, with an <ul> inside displaying the component's elements.

Comment: The [ngClass] binds to a property of the component that changes on the (click) event. I will create a generic component and put it on github when i'll have time.